# Is it possible to preview code start in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Well i am coming from Visual Studio where there is a feature to see a preview of the start of any code that isn't in the editor. ex if you are down at the end of an if statement or end of a method in C#, or even tag closings in HTML.

Here is a pic of what i mean. And sorry i can't even search for that cause i don't know what such feature is called.

[image]

Any extension might be nice.

Edit: this is actually a Resharper Ultimate feature called `highlight matching delimiter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available in VS code.

Comment: do you know any extension that can do that ?

Comment: unfortunately no.